# Tag suggestion: RainbowTable and HashTable

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a fair number of questions that refer to RainbowTables or HashTables in one way or another.  Given that RainbowTables and HashTables:

1. Serve different purposes
2. Are easily confused
3. Similar, but not close enough for be called a synonym of each other

**Question**

- Should we have tags representing each of them?
- If the asker tags their question "HashTable" when they really want to discuss "RainbowTables" should the question be retagged as appropriate?

The goal is so that I can add these questions to "favorite" or "ignored" as appropriate, and also easily search within that body of knowledge.

Comment: I only found a single question about hash-tables. So I don't see why we should have a tag for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that currently this isn't an issue, as @codes pointed out. As we grow out may end up being needed, but the general SE consensus is that there is no need to create tags until they serve a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we need a tag for either hash tables *or* rainbow tables.  Hash tables aren't widely mentioned.  Rainbow tables are easy to search for (just search for rainbow table!) and don't seem to need a special tag of their own.  So, I don't think any new tags are needed.